# Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed Error while running catkin_make

Tags: ros, catkin, realsense

I am working on intel realsense camera R200 in ros kinetic. After installing
While installing Intel RealSense SDK for Linux, it didn't show any error but after *catkin_make* command the following error occured:

> Base path: /home/janhvi/catkin_ws Source space:
>   /home/janhvi/catkin_ws/src Build space: /home/janhvi/catkin_ws/build
>   Devel space: /home/janhvi/catkin_ws/devel Install space:
>   /home/janhvi/catkin_ws/install
>
> #### #
>
> Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/janhvi/catkin_ws/build"
>
> #### #
>
> #### #
>
> Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/janhvi/catkin_ws/build"
>   
>   [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp [  0%] Built target
>
> _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_EulerAnglesWithConfidence
>   [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_TrackingConfig [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_Landmark [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp [  0%] Built target
>   geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_StopTracking [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_UserInfo [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_PersonModuleState [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_FrameTest [  0%] Built target _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_Wave [
>   0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_Recognition [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_Pointing [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_StartTracking [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_RectWithConfidence [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_SaveRecognitionDB [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_EulerAngles [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_Gesture [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_LandmarksInfo [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_SkeletonJoint [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_LoadRecognitionDB [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_RecognitionRegister [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_Gestures [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_Frame [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_check_deps_User [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py [  0%] Built target
>   std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs [  0%] Built target
>   geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs [  0%] Built target
>   sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs [  0%] Built target
>   std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp [  0%] Built target
>   sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp [  0%] Built target
>   std_msgs_generate_messages_eus [  0%] Built target
>   geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp [  0%] Built target
>   geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus [  0%] Built target
>   tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py [  0%] Built target
>   sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus [  0%] Built target
>   roscpp_generate_messages_lisp [  0%] Built target
>   roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs [  0%] Built target
>   roscpp_generate_messages_eus [  0%] Built target
>   roscpp_generate_messages_cpp [  0%] Built target
>   rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs [  0%] Built target
>   rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus [  0%] Built target
>   rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp [  0%] Built target
>   roscpp_generate_messages_py [  0%] Built target
>   rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp [  0%] Built target
>   bond_generate_messages_cpp [  0%] Built target
>   rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py [  0%] Built target
>   bond_generate_messages_lisp [  0%] Built target
>   nodelet_generate_messages_nodejs [  0%] Built target
>   bond_generate_messages_nodejs [  0%] Built target
>   nodelet_generate_messages_eus [  0%] Built target
>   nodelet_generate_messages_cpp [  0%] Built target
>   bond_generate_messages_py [  0%] Built target
>   nodelet_generate_messages_lisp [  0%] Built target
>   bond_generate_messages_eus [  0%] Built target
>   nodelet_generate_messages_py [  0%] Built target
>   actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs [  0%] Built target
>   tf_generate_messages_py [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_camera_generate_messages_check_deps_Extrinsics [  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp [  0%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_camera_generate_messages_check_deps_IMUInfo [  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp [  0%] Built target
>   tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp [  0%] Built target
>   tf_generate_messages_nodejs [  0%] Built target
>   actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus [  0%] Built target
>   actionlib_generate_messages_eus [  0%] Built target
>   tf_generate_messages_cpp [  0%] Built target
>   _catkin_empty_exported_target [  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_eus [  0%] Built target
>   actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp [  0%] Built target
>   actionlib_generate_messages_py [  0%] Built target
>   actionlib_generate_messages_cpp [  0%] Built target
>   actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs [  0%] Built target
>   actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py [  0%] Built target
>   tf_generate_messages_lisp [  0%] Built target
>   tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp [  0%] Built target
>   tf2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs [  0%] Built target
>   tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus [  1%] Built target gtest [  2%] Built
>   target realsense_ros_camera_generate_messages_nodejs [  3%] Built
>   target realsense_ros_camera_generate_messages_py [  4%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_camera_generate_messages_lisp [  5%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_camera_generate_messages_eus [  5%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_check_deps_Location3D [  5%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_check_deps_cpu_gpu [  5%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_check_deps_TrackedObject [  5%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_check_deps_ObjectArray [  5%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_check_deps_ObjectsInBoxes [  5%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_check_deps_ObjectInBox [  5%] Built target _realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_check_deps_UI [ 
>   5%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_check_deps_Object [  5%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_check_deps_TrackedObjectsArray [  5%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_check_deps_Rect [  5%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_slam_generate_messages_check_deps_TrackingAccuracy [  5%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_slam_generate_messages_check_deps_SaveOutput [ 14%] Built target realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_cpp [ 24%] Built
>   target realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_py [ 35%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_nodejs [ 44%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_lisp [ 44%] Built target
>   _realsense_ros_slam_generate_messages_check_deps_Reset [ 54%] Built target realsense_ros_person_generate_messages_eus [ 55%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_camera_generate_messages_cpp [ 60%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_cpp [ 65%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_lisp [ 70%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_eus [ 73%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_person [ 78%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_py [ 82%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_object_generate_messages_nodejs [ 83%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_slam_generate_messages_cpp [ 84%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_slam_generate_messages_lisp [ 86%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_slam_generate_messages_py [ 88%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_slam_generate_messages_nodejs [ 89%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_person_generate_messages [ 90%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_slam_generate_messages_eus [ 90%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_camera_generate_messages [ 90%] Linking CXX executable
>   /home/janhvi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/realsense_ros_person/realsense_ros_person_sample
>   [ 91%] Built target realsense_ros_camera [ 92%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_tests_camera [ 92%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_object_generate_messages [ 92%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_slam_generate_messages [ 94%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_object [ 95%] Built target realsense_ros_slam [ 95%]
>   Built target realsense_ros_object_sample1 [ 97%] Built target
>   realsense_ros_object_viewer
>   CMakeFiles/realsense_ros_person_sample.dir/src/sample/TrackingRenderer/Viewer.cpp.o:
>   In function `Viewer::Viewer(bool)': Viewer.cpp:(.text+0x97): undefined
>   reference to`cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
>   Viewer.cpp:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to
>   `cv::setMouseCallback(cv::String const&, void (*)(int, int, int, int,
>   void*), void*)' Viewer.cpp:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to`
>   cv::startWindowThread()' Viewer.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined
>   reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
>   Viewer.cpp:(.text+0x117): undefined reference to`
>   cv::startWindowThread()'
>   CMakeFiles/realsense_ros_person_sample.dir/src/sample/TrackingRenderer/Viewer.cpp.o:
>   In function `Viewer::ShowImage(cv::Mat)': Viewer.cpp:(.text+0x1dd):
>   undefined reference to`cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray
>   const&)' Viewer.cpp:(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to
>   `cv::waitKey(int)'
>   CMakeFiles/realsense_ros_person_sample.dir/src/sample/TrackingRenderer/Viewer.cpp.o:
>   In function`Viewer::ShowDepth(cv::Mat)': Viewer.cpp:(.text+0x29f):
>   undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray
>   const&)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   realsense_samples_ros/realsense_ros_person/CMakeFiles/realsense_ros_person_sample.dir/build.make:209: recipe for target
>   '/home/janhvi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/realsense_ros_person/realsense_ros_person_sample'
>   failed make[2]: ***
>   [/home/janhvi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/realsense_ros_person/realsense_ros_person_sample]
>   Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1340: recipe for target
>   'realsense_samples_ros/realsense_ros_person/CMakeFiles/realsense_ros_person_sample.dir/all'
>   failed make[1]: ***
>   [realsense_samples_ros/realsense_ros_person/CMakeFiles/realsense_ros_person_sample.dir/all]
>   Error 2 Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all]
>   Error 2 Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed

I tried to source the file but same error is occurring.
Can anyone help solving this issue?

Comment: Please provide some more context information and the packages your are trying to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem Is That Your Linker Cannot Find OpenCV Shared Objects.

- Check In Your CMakeList File For Linking Your Executables To OpenCV Libs
- Check Your OpenCV Installation (Check Path And Even Compile Something Simple With OpenCV libs)

Comment: I tried to include OpenCV in a CMakeLists.txt in realsense ros person folder in catkin_ws & it worked!!